# Overloading << Cannot Access Inherited Private Data

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, friend

I am trying to overload the `operator<<` from the class `second`. The problem is some of the data I am trying to access is private in class `first`. Why am I unable to access the private data since I am using the friend function?

I found that the overload is only working with non-inherited private data.

```
class first
{
public:

    student(string a, string b, float c, int d);

private:
    string a;
    string b;
    float c;
    int d;
    int e;
    static int count;   
};


class second : public first
{
public:

    second(string a, string b, float c, int d, string f);


    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output, second &dS);
    friend istream &operator >> (istream &input, second &dS);

private:
    string f; 
};


// Separate File

ostream &operator <<(ostream& output, second& dS){

    output << iS.a << endl;

    output << iS.f << endl;


return output;
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
overload.cpp:27:18: error: 'a' is a private member of 'first'
    output << dS.a << endl;
                 ^
./example.hpp:51:9: note: declared private here
        string a;
```

Comment: its because second doesnt have access to those variables. They have to be protected instead of private if you want to have access to them in  child class

Comment: `class second` **also** cannot access those variables.  That is how `private` works.  They are privately owned by`class first`.

Comment: Your friends can see your private parts, but they can't see your parents' private parts.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```cpp
friend ostream &operator << (ostream &output, second &dS);
```

you are allowing some external function with that signature to have access to any internal attribute/member your `second` class has access. That means `operator<<` will have access to the attribute `f` even though it is private. However, your `second` class does not have access to the private data from the base class. Thus, it cannot give that access to a `friend` function.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, the second Class does not have access to the private members of the first class. You could try writing some set and get methods in the first class. The get methods would return the value (that i'm assume you're seeking). You could call this function in the second class. Not sure if that's going overboard for what you're looking for though. Might just want to do the overloading in the fist class

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the real solution that I have to go with!